# How to make a server for a mobile app in Bluemix

Tags: mobile, server, ibm-cloud

So I am really new to Bluemix,, I was told using Bluemix to create a server which will be connected to an Android App was a good idea, how true is it? And if it is, how do I do it(you don't have to guide me step by step, if you do I dont mind, just posting a good video or link where I can learn about it will help)? If not what other options do you recommend. Btw I am making the app on Android Studio.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for the Stack Overflow platform. This is a forum for asking and answering programming questions. Please post your Bluemix question to https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/ or check out the Bluemix docs on building Android apps https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobile/android/android.html

Answer (score 0):

@Pablo García, In simple words, you have to create an application in Bluemix that is bound to a Mobile Service and your Android App should be configured to interact with the application in Bluemix.  If you want to get started with Android app to work with Bluemix, please read this article
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/library/mo-android-mobiledata-app/index.html

Comment: I have already seen this video. I still can not find how to make the web server work. I try to enter the admin console in bluemix but it does not allow me

Comment: @Pablo García, can you please provide more information on what exactly you are trying to do?  Based on your question and your response to my answer, I am understanding that you are trying to see if you can set up  an Application Server like Liberty and want to have an Application running on this server that will work with App on an Android device.   If that is what you are looking, please provide response here or open a new question.

Comment: Ya what I was trying to de was create a server somewhere and then connect my app to it on, but I have already managed to do it on Java Eclipse using sockets since I had no progress using Bluemix